# how to enable Elasticsearch on LAN

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I just installed Elasticsarch 7.5.0 on my ubuntu server. I can get elasticsearch from the localhost and I want to be able to access it from another computer, but this is not working. I tried config from [the official site](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html): `network.host: 0.0.0.0`, `network.host: 192.168.1.2`, but when I restart elasticseach after changing my config, I get this:

```
Job for elasticsearch.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status elasticsearch.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

I have also tried network.host: *global*, but nothing seem to be working. Any Idea what is the issue here?
my elasticsearch.yml file looks like this:

```
# ======================== Elasticsearch Configuration =========================
#
# NOTE: Elasticsearch comes with reasonable defaults for most settings.
#       Before you set out to tweak and tune the configuration, make sure you
#       understand what are you trying to accomplish and the consequences.
#
# The primary way of configuring a node is via this file. This template lists
# the most important settings you may want to configure for a production cluster.
#
# Please consult the documentation for further information on configuration options:
# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/index.html
#
# ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
#cluster.name: my-application
#
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
#
#node.name: node-1
#
# Add custom attributes to the node:
#
#node.attr.rack: r1
#
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
#
# Path to log files:
#
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
#
# ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
#
# Lock the memory on startup:
#
#bootstrap.memory_lock: true
#
# Make sure that the heap size is set to about half the memory available
# on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this
# limit.
#
# Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
#
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):



#network.host: 0.0.0.0
#network.bind_host: 0.0.0.0
#network.publish_host: 0.0.0.0
#



#
#network.host: 192.168.0.1
#network.host: 10.10.10.16
#network.host: 0.0.0.0
network.host: '_global_'
#
# Set a custom porti for HTTP:
#
#http.port: 9200
#
# For more information, consult the network module documentation.
#
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when this node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
#discovery.seed_hosts: ["127.0.0.1", "0.0.0.0"]
#
# Bootstrap the cluster using an initial set of master-eligible nodes:
#
#cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1", "node-2"]
#
# For more information, consult the discovery and cluster formation module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Gateway -----------------------------------
#
# Block initial recovery after a full cluster restart until N nodes are started:
#
#gateway.recover_after_nodes: 3
#
# For more information, consult the gateway module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
#
# Require explicit names when deleting indices:
#
#action.destructive_requires_name: true
```

Comment: look in your /var/log/elasticsearch/*.log files.... what's in there... When you bind to 0.0.0.0, it executes extra tests because it thinks you're ready to go to production.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the issue:

```
network.host: _enp0s3_
discovery.seed_hosts: 0.0.0.0
```

after setting these parameters it worked find.